# Modulo and Division operators working together even though not connected whatsoever

Tags: php

Two choices between modulo and division, however, both outputs show up regardless which one you choose

```
if ($_POST['op'] == divide && $num1 == 0) {
                    echo "Sorry, you can't divide by zero.";
            } else {
        echo "$num1 divided by $num2 equals $divideresult";
    } if ($_POST['op'] == remainder) {
        echo "When $num1 is divided by $num2, the remainder is $remresult";
```

Output is "0 divided by 1 equals 0When 0 is divided by 1, the remainder is 0 even though I only chose modulo and not division.

Comment: You need `else if` for the second check don't you?

Comment: `$_POST['op'] == 'divide'` quotes required

Comment: also missing end curly braces for last `if` condition

Comment: @Carcigenicate, yes, but my website crashes with a parse error. Unexpected if statement.

Comment: @don't angry me, I just didnt copy the next line

Comment: @idontDownVote that doesnt change anything as every other variable is missing quotes and the operations still work

Comment: without them you should see a "Use of undefined constant" notice. its basic php syntax

Comment: It works just fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Exception not being caught, error message not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583377/php-exception-not-being-caught-error-message-not-showing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Output is "0 divided by 1 equals 0When 0 is divided by 1, the remainder is 0 even though I only chose modulo and not division.**

because this is how it is getting executed. When you chose the `divide` option it goes to `else` block of `divide` because it doesn't match so echo `echo "0 divided by 1 equals 0"` and as other `if` condition is on same level then it checks for `remainder` condition and echo `When 0 is divided by 1, the remainder is 0`

**This is how it is getting executed.**

```
<?php
if ($_POST['op'] == 'divide' && $num1 == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, you can't divide by zero.";
} else {
    echo "$num1 divided by $num2 equals $divideresult";
} 

// this condition also get executed every time though you want to check for divide because both divide and remainder are on same level
if ($_POST['op'] == 'remainder') {
    echo "When $num1 is divided by $num2, the remainder is $remresult";
    //your other code goes here
}    
?>
```

**This is how it should be I guess**

```
<?php
if ($_POST['op'] == 'divide') {
    if($num1 == 0){
        echo "Sorry, you can't divide by zero.";
    } else {
        echo "$num1 divided by $num2 equals $divideresult";
    }
} else if ($_POST['op'] == 'remainder') {
    echo "When $num1 is divided by $num2, the remainder is $remresult";
    //your other code goes here
}    
?>
```

Comment: This works, but if num2 is zero the program crashes. and if i do ($num1 == 0 || $num2 == 0) the program still crashes

Comment: Outputs the same thing

Comment: @Gabe I've **Edited** my answer. Have a look again

Comment: Yes this is how it should be. Thank you

Comment: @Gabe You're welcome. glad it helps you some how. Best of luck :)